# custom keyboard - how to dispatch event which signals the UITextField to update the text accordingaly

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a custom keypad through a collection of buttons, which function like a regular keypad provided in iphone.

Now series of action that should occur
-text field is selected
-user presses the button
-text field is designated as first responder
-something like key event is launched so that text field is updated according to the character associated with the button.

If above supposition of flow is correct, please guide me how to get around the last step. I am newbie to iphone, so please let me know if am missing any of the basic.

Answer (score 0):

Found an other way which did the needed by simulating the behaviour of keyEvent( which i doubt if exist in iphone sdk).

Basic outline of the procedure is like
-push the content to pasteboard
-call the paste function on UITextField

so when button is pressed, content corresponding to the button is copied to pasteboard and then paste function is called on the UITextField, so that the content get inserted into it.

Detailed description of steps can be found here:
http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/09/insert-text-at-current-cursor-location.html